# Spring Data usage in WAS8 with EJB and CDI

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi, spring-data-jpa, websphere-8

i've got the following problem.

I'm using spring data in a Websphere 8 environment with Spring Data repositories created by CDI. The EntityManager is provided by a stateless session bean with a producer method. This works for now but I got a use case to create a timer on server startup. So there is a bean with an @Startup annotation. The EJB timer is a singleton bean which is injected into the startup class and used in the postConstruct method of this class. Into that timer, there is a service bean injected (EJB) and this service has a Spring Data repository injected via CDI to get the timer interval form the DB.

So the problem is. When WAS is starting, the CDI context is not completely initialized at the startup time. So the injection points cannot be satisfied.

There is a WAS-JVM property to start the CDI context earlier but than the problem is, that the producer method in the EntityManagerProvider is not called and throws a null pointer.

Is There anybody who had already a problem close to that use case or with an idea what to do or what to change about this architecture to get it running without exceptions ?

Comment: You talk about both `@Startup` and a timer. Does that mean you're setting a programmatic timer such as in http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html#giqlt? The answer might depend on that fine detail.

Comment: Yes, exactly, in intervalTimer is created. Thanks for your answer :)